# ng-select max height dropdown panel

Tags: css, angular-ngselect

I'm trying to set the max height of an `ng-select` control and I'm using the following css

```
ng-dropdown-panel.custom-class {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

...but it isn't having the desired effect. I have `[multiple]="true"` and `appendto="body"` on the ng-select.

How can I specify the max height correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what I needed by doing the following

```
html .ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items {
    max-height: 120px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```